# Any dangers of sharing /home partition between two distros?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, linux-mint, kubuntu, home-folder

I have a laptop with a 250GB HDD. I have an existing installation of Kubuntu across three partitions (A 20GB one for `/`, 2GB for swap, and something like 97GB for `/home`). If I add another partition, use that as `/` for a Mint 13 install, and then use the existing `/home` partition as Linux Mint's home folder (different user names), are there any dangers (besides badly done partitioning, and other dumb things like that)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work *if* you take care with uids.

Consider the following example:
In Kubunto you have two users: John, uid 100, and jane with uid 101

In Mint you make a few users: Jane (100), test2 (101), test2(102),  Doe (103) etc

/home/john/ will is accessable by john in your original Kubunto.
However  in mint /home/john/ belongs to jane (wo has uid 100 in the mint example).

Comment: All of the accounts will be mine, so that's fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It Should work depending on where and how you install it. I have a 500GB Hard Drive With Ubuntu 12.04, Linux mint 13 Cinnamon (or something like that),tinycore+, and archlinux, and 4mLinux and they all have a 100Gb partition and they run fine.
(Ubuntu Has A External Hard Drive though)